# Why does the value of a boolean change after stepping out of a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean

After I click on a li-element where the class-attribute contains "disabled selected", disabled gets the value "true" but after stepping out the function the last if-statement is called.

```
    var disabled = false;
    $("li").click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "disabled selected") {
            disabled = true;
        }
    });
    if (disabled) {
        alert("disabled is true");
    }
    if (!disabled) {
        alert("disabled is false");
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code that has the `if (disabled)...` statements in it? As it stands in your example, those checks will be run as soon as they are encountered; before the onclick function.

Comment: Could you add your html code as well, or even better, reproduce the error here: http://www.jsfiddle.com

Comment: Are you saying the alert inside the `if(!disabled)` block is displayed _after_ you click?

Comment: You should maybe test the class names with `if ( $(this).hasClass('disabled') && $(this).hasClass('selected') )`

Comment: If @Tassisto knew the answer, he would not ask the question. Critiquing the code does not help.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, !disabled is being fired

Comment: What is the context for the above code? It makes no sense at all for the `!disabled` alert to be displayed _after_ you click on a `li` unless there is more code that you haven't shown us. @Emil - I think Didier's suggestion was intended as a way to potentially fix the problem - testing multiple classes with `.attr()` as shown in the question isn't the most reliable of methods...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move both the `if` statements inside the click handler.

```
var disabled = false;
$("li").click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "disabled selected") {
        disabled = true;
    }
    if (disabled) {
        alert("disabled is true");
    }
    else {
        alert("disabled is false");
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the first if-test is okay and that disabled is set to true? Try adding `alert('setting disabled = true')` before the line that sets disabled, just to verify that it is in fact being executed.

Comment: Its working for me. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/BxYd6/
My guess is that your disabled is not true in the first `if` condition

Answer (score 1):

The last two if tests are run before the click event handler, so the value of `disabled` hasn't been changed yet then.

Answer (score 1):

The callback is not invoked until the 'li' is clicked. However, the proceeding two 'if' statements are executed immediately. You'll want to place them within the callback.

```
var disabled = false;
$("li").click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "disabled selected") {
        disabled = true;
    }
    if (disabled) {
     alert("disabled is true");
    }
    if (!disabled) {
     alert("disabled is false");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is executed when the `li` element is clicked. When the script is initially evaluated, the click event has not been fired.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is two-fold.

First, as pointed out by several posters, you need to put those `if` tests inside the click handler. As it stands now, they execute outside the click handler's scope, which I suspect is not when you want them to execute.

Second, the `if ($(this).attr("class") == "disabled selected") {` will only get you a "truthy" value if the class string is `'disabled selected'`. If the class string is `'selected disabled'` (or `'otherClass disabled selected'` or `'disabled selected draggable'`, etc.) then you will get a `false` value returned as a result of the comparison.

Try:

```
$("li").click(function () {
    var i = $(this); //Multiple variables used for better step-line debugging.
    var hasDisabled = i.hasClass('disabled');
    var hasSelected = i.hasClass('selected');
    var disabled = false;
    if (hasDisabled && hasSelected) {
        disabled = true;
    }
    if (disabled) {
        alert("disabled is true");
    }
    if (!disabled) {
        alert("disabled is false");
    }
});
```